# Facing error on deployment server, i have just FTP access but no access of source code?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis

After deploy application on server i am facing this error, application is developed in `asp.net mvc`.

```
Configuration Error
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Helpers, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error:

An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Source File: E:\web\brewgrco\web.config    Line: 30
```

I have check version of `system.web.helpers` is same as mentioned in `web.config` files both in `views` folder also in root of web.config as well, I have just access `FTP` but no access to source code, please help me to fix it.

Comment: what is your app pool's version number in IIS in the server? and ave you veried you web.config is correct, no format error ? if nothing works then you can try setting customErrors mode off to see the error then revert this setting

Comment: its already customErrors mode is off in web.config and i already told you i dont have access of capnel, i have just `FTP` access

Comment: You will have to escalate this to whoever developed that web app. It makes no sense to deploy without a developer standing by and pointing out the issues as soon as possible. For this specific error, .NET assemblies should be in `bin` folder, not anywhere else. Since you seem to only know some deployment steps, it would also be hard for you to understand what the suggestions like this mean.